# how to set fixed position of element?

Tags: c#, winforms, position

How to set fixed position of element in C# Window Forms?
For example: I have a label and when I scroll down, label should move down.

I know it from CSS (Cascading Style Sheets): "position: fixed".
I know Web technologies has nothing to do with winforms, but you can see the different between these two divs:

```
<div style="position: static;"></div>
<div style="position: fixed;"></div> <!-- Wanted in WF -->
```

Comment: Everything in winforms is fixed position by default.

Comment: But when you scroll, it does not move! It has a static position!

Comment: please edit your question and add more details about what you're trying to do and what problems are you facing.

Answer (score 1):

All controls on a Windows form, unless you use something like the `FlowLayoutPanel`, are fixed. They all have a `Location` property, an `X` and a `Y`. However, what you need to remember is that if you want something *docked* in a specific spot you have a couple options. Either set its `Dock` property so it's *docked* where you want it, or place it where you want it and set its `Anchor` property.

Keep in mind that if you wanted a *footer*, you'd need to add the remainder of your controls to a `Panel` so that they could scroll whilst the *footer* stayed in place with one of the aforementioned scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

As HighCore commented, it is correct that by default everything in winforms is fixed positioned.

However you may also find it interesting to read [How to: Set the Screen Location of Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52aha046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Which is terribly bad, and makes winforms completely useless when dealing with multiple resolutions / DPI settings / screen sizes.

Comment: except CSS is a Web Technology and has nothing to do with winforms, your comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: @HighCore:- Yes I got it wrong. I was thinking of Web. My bad